# Python 2.7: No module named hexchat

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, twitch, hexchat

I'm trying to write a Python script that does something with the inputs from the IRC chat that is connected to twitch.

However, when I do import hexchat, python keeps telling me there is no module named hexchat. I'm using Pycharm btw. I just want to be able to use the functionality in the hexchat module. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to first download and install `Hex Chat` module from here [Downloads](http://hexchat.github.io/downloads.html) and then do the `import hexchat`.

For Linux - `sudo apt-get install hexchat`

Documentation for Python API is here [Documentation](https://hexchat.readthedocs.org/en/latest/script_python.html)

Answer (score 0):

You load scripts **inside** hexchat. *Window > Plugins and Scripts > Load*.

Comment: How can I load a script if I can't import hexchat in the first place to write my script to begin with? Sorry, I'm utterly confused, am I missing something?

Comment: When hexchat loads the script it provides the module.

Comment: Hi, I tried it but I get this error:

 "Unknown file type C:\Users\Yicheng Gong\Desktop\twitch\irc_script.py. Maybe you need to install the Perl or Python plugin?
 Usage: LOAD [-e] <file>, loads a plugin or script"

How exactly do you download the Python Plugin? I went to https://hexchat.github.io/downloads.html,
downloaded Hexchat 2.10.2, Python 2.7.10 for scripts, and even source.

and this is inside the script(just for testing for now):

import hexchat

__module_name__ = "helloworld"
__module_version__ = "1.0"
__module_description__ = "Python module example"

hexchat.prnt("Hi everyone!")

Comment: The Python plugin is an install option in HexChat's installer.

Comment: Hi TingPing, thanks I was able to load the script, but my python interpreter still can't find the module. Is this suppose to happen?
It says can't find hexchat module, but I can load in a simple script that says hi to the chat and it works

Comment: Yes, only hexchat has the module, it is internal.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue on `Windows 10` but I managed to resolve it by loading `.py` scripts in `Hexchat` like the below:

```
/py load "C:\where\your\file\is.py"
```

You also want to have module info in your `.py` file too otherwise `Hexchat` will complain:

```
__module_name__ = "helloworld"
__module_version__ = "1.0"
__module_description__ = "Python module example"
```